# NPM and Bower how to use both for the same pacakge

Tags: npm, bower

I have some libraries that I want available for my front end Bower packages and my back end NPM packages.  Is there are way to handle this without creating 2 sets of packages in both Bower and NPM?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of bower, and use only NPM. Here is a good read:
https://www.quora.com/Why-use-Bower-when-there-is-npm